# Using Scanner.next() to get text input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get text input from the keyboard in Java 6.  I am new to the language and whenever i run the following code, I get this error:

```
package test1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean quit = false;
    while (!quit){
        Scanner keyIn;
        String c = "x";
        while (c != "y" && c != "n") {
            keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            c = keyIn.next();
            keyIn.close();
        }
        if (c == "n")
            quit = true;
    }
 }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
at test1.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Am I mis-using the next() method?  I thought it would wait for user input but it looks like it isn't and throwing the exception saying that there is nothing left in the scanner.

Comment: what is your code doing exactly and what's the input?

Comment: all this is is trying to get the user to input "y" or "n" and if its "y" keep looping, otherwise exit.  the error happens no matter which letter i press.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that you are calling `keyIn.close()` after you use the scanner once, which not only closes the `Scanner` but also `System.in`. The very next iteration you create a new `Scanner` which promptly blows up because `System.in` is now closed. To fix that, what you should do is only create a scanner once before you enter the `while` loop, and skip the `close()` call entirely since you don't want to close `System.in`.

After fixing that the program still won't work because of the `==` and `!=` string comparisons you do. When comparing strings in Java you must use `equals()` to compare the string contents. When you use `==` and `!=` you are comparing the object references, so these comparisons will always return false in your code. [Always use `equals()` to compare strings.](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/cantrell/archives/2003/04/how_equals_work.html)

```
while (!quit){
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String c = "x";
    while (!c.equals("y") && !c.equals("n")) {
        c = keyIn.next();
    }
    if (c.equals("n"))
        quit = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer solved mine problem too!
I didn't know that 'in.close();' also closes 'system.in' !

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate strings you have to use .equals

while(!c.equals("y")) { do stuff...

Answer (score 1):

- declare your Scanner reference outside your loops. you don't have to create it and close it every time.
- compare string text with the method `equals`, not with the operator `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using nextLine() and only looking at the first element in the string that is returned.

The != and == will only work when used against characters or other primitive types, that will only work in c#.  You will need to use .equals to ensure you are checking for proper equality.