# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException cann't write to a class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedwriter

**So I have this code :**

```
package Firstpack;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("1. Add a record ");
        System.out.println("2. See all records ");
        System.out.println("3. See a category");
        System.out.println("4. Total spend(Year)");
        System.out.println("5. Spend in a month");
        System.out.println("6. Chose by index");
        System.out.println("7. Exit ");

        System.out.print(">");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int enteredInt = in.nextInt();
        in.close();

        switch (enteredInt) {
        case 1:
            recording();
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print(" You have chosen -> See all records");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print(" You have chosen -> See a category");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print(" You have chosen -> Total spend(Year)");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.print(" You have chosen -> Spend in a month");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.print(" You have chosen -> Chose by index");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.print(" Bye! ");
            break;
        default:
            menu();
        }

    }

    public static void recording() {
        System.out.println(" You have chosen -> Add a record");

        record rec = new record();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Amount > ");
        rec.amount = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Category > ");
        rec.category = in.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Details > ");
        rec.details = in.next();

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("findme.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(String.valueOf(rec.amount));
            bw.write(rec.category);
            bw.write(rec.details);

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
    }
}
```

And it throws me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at Firstpack.Main.recording(Main.java:68)
    at Firstpack.Main.menu(Main.java:25)
    at Firstpack.Main.main(Main.java:82)
```

And I have no idea how to solve this.  What is wrong here?

Comment: What is at line 68 in Main.java?

Comment: What is the definition of class `record`?

Comment: Consider using `java.io.Console` instead of `Scanner`.

Comment: It works fine for me.  Try writing hard coded values to the file, if that works, ensure the values are good before you're writing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the call to `in.close()` in your menu method.  Not only does `in.close()` close the `Scanner` object, but it also happens to close `System.in` as well.  When you enter 1 as the menu selection your `recording()` method gets called which creates a new `Scanner` which tries to use the now closed `System.in`.

This is a post that addresses a similar issue:
[Trying to write a method that checks user input in JAVA, getting NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410173/trying-to-write-a-method-that-checks-user-input-in-java-getting-nosuchelementex)